# Can I use other node.js libraries in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I was playing around with an idea and wanted to get some json from another site. I found with node.js people seem to use http.get to accomplish this however I discovered it wasn't that easy in Meteor. Is there another way to do this or a way to access http so I can call get? I wanted an interval that could collect data from an external source to augment the data the clients would interact with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you can get at `require` this way:

```
var http = __meteor_bootstrap__.require('http');
```

Note that this'll probably only work on the server, so make sure it's protected with a check for `Meteor.is_server`.

Comment: any idea on how to get transitive dependencies to work? Try aws-lib for example.

Comment: Meteor.is_server is now Meteor.isServer

Comment: also add `var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;` to use the require syntax you're used to.

Comment: debergalis's answer should be upvoted now that Meteor.http has been added.

Answer (score 8):

This is much easier now with `Meteor.http`.  First run `meteor add http`, then you can do something like this:

```
// common code
stats = new Meteor.Collection('stats');

// server code: poll service every 10 seconds, insert JSON result in DB.
Meteor.setInterval(function () {
  var res = Meteor.http.get(SOME_URL);
  if (res.statusCode === 200)
    stats.insert(res.data);
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Meteor.http` if you want to handle http. To add other node.js libraries you can use [meteorhacks:npm](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm)

`meteor add meteorhacks:npm`

Create a`pacakges.json` file and add all the required packages name and versions.

```
{
  "redis": "0.8.2",
  "github": "0.1.8"
}
```